# installed safari on ubuntu 14.04 using wine but not able to browse

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have installed Safari 5.3 using wine successfully. But I am not able to browse websites using Safari. It's even not showing the home page of Apple. OS ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

`playonlinux` offers an installation script to install Safari in WINE, see [here](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-118-Safari.html).

1. (if not already done) install `playonlinux` and start the program

   ```
   sudo apt install playonlinux && playonlinux
   ```
2. in the `playonlinux` window, click `+ Install` and search for “Safari”
3. double click the “Safari” entry and follow the installation instructions, the script will download and install everything needed

Comment: Installing is not the problem here I think.
I have a similar issue, where Safari (version 5.0) says "Safari can’t open the page.` for most pages (not all)